# Google Web Designer or Adobe Edge Animate Alternative for Linux?

Tags: wine, adobe, google

GWD and Edge Animate have been very helpful on Windows, but I haven't came across anything uniquely close for Linux. I've used Amaya and Kompozer for months and has been fairly helpful. However I'd like to see something like GWD or Edge Animate available for Linux.

Now I did try running those two apps with WINE, but haven't had any luck. Has anyone been able to run either of these apps via WINE successfully?

In addition I was wondering if there's something like GWD or Edge Animate available for Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Google Web Designer for Linux (Debian/Ubuntu/Fedora/openSUSE).

You can download it from 
[here](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/).

Comment: When I posted this question GWD was only available for Windows and Mac OS X. Quite frankly I forgot this question was still up. I knew about it's release for Linux a few months ago thanks to OmgUbuntu. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Until someone invents something tomorrow. I decided to work on my own as an experiment, but also so others can have a nice web designing experience without any code. This way I can focus more on designing my layout and less on writing the design itself.

The app is called [Mirrored Mobile Design](http://mmd.sourceforge.net/)
[image]
[image]

**Features**

- [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wysiwyg) Styled Editing
- Responsive & Interactive Design
- Available For: [Linux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mmd/files/mmd-linux.tar.gz/download)/[Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.michael.mmdesign)/[Online](http://mmd.sourceforge.net/app/)/[Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ekndodkbcpninebdijaaambkbdglbalh/)
- MMD encourages class based syntaxes
- Pseudo class selectors via Global Styles
- Integrated Media Queries for Responsive Design.

Last but not least you can download the source code from [Github](https://github.com/mikethedj4/mmd) or [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mmd/).

Answer (score 1):

Are you after a general HTML5 / CSS3 authoring tool, or the animation capabilities of Edge Animate specifically?

If the former (generatl HTML5 / CSS3 authoring), you could have a look at these online tools (in some kind of prioritized order):

- [WebFlow](https://webflow.com/)
- [Moqups](https://moqups.com/)
- [Macaw](http://macaw.co/) (Not released yet...)

If the latter (animation tool), the only one I know that will run on Linux (due to being an online tool) is:

- [Mixeek](http://www.mixeek.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Aloha Online Editor.

Aloha Editor is a semantic Rich Text Editor framework written in Javascript with best support of xHTML5. You can integrate it in a CMS, blog, wiki software or any other project where you need to edit content with a web based tool.<sup>[Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org/index.php)</sup>

For more info see [Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org/index.php)